# How do I get Windows 10 to draw 1080p in 4K resolution?

Tags: windows-10, 4k-resolution

Due to my monitor being 28" with 4K... things display just 15% or so too small for my eyes. I love having a monitor in my face but they say thats bad for your eyes?

My 4K monitor when set to 1920x1080 looks disgusting...blurry pixels, terrible upscaling!

Is there an uscaling tech that does a better job that plugs into windows?
Is it because of ClearType or some other MS display technology?

Comment: You can’t draw 1080p in 4k resolution, I mean there is upscaling, but you don’t think that looks good enough.  Is there a reason you don’t just set the resolution to 4k?

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah so I'm looking for ways to improve the effect that is rendered. THere is upscaling as well as certain display technolohies such as cleartype that change the way critical elements like text are drawn. Its too far away from me eyes at this time... I simply want to do it for my personal comfort

Comment: Depending on what graphics card you have, it may be able to do what you want. So, what graphics card do you have?

Comment: Presumably the new "integer scaling" methods on the latest GPUs should effectively achieve what is asked. 1080p scaled up to 4 pixel squares with no interpolation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the IntegerScaler App: https://tanalin.com/en/projects/integer-scaler/

It's freem an can do pixel-perfect (no interpolation) 'integer scaling' on windowed games or a single desktop application.

Comment: Interested in marking this correct answer. Are there any references to this site other than itself? I can't get much information about Tanalin.

Comment: not much, but I've found those website that talk about it: https://bit.ly/2ZIQXdx   https://bit.ly/2XojJNE    https://bit.ly/3eh03lo

Comment: @chrips I’m the IntegerScaler author. Tanalin is my last (family) name used as my site domain. The domain is registered in 2004; I’m on Stack Overflow since 2012; I’m an [integer-scaling](https://tanalin.com/en/articles/integer-scaling/) fan and evangelist for 5 years — since switching to a [4K monitor](https://tanalin.com/en/blog/2015/05/dell-p2415q-review/). Note that IntegerScaler is mainly for _games_. For Windows itself and regular apps, consider using the “Integer scaling” feature of modern GPUs. For images on webpages, use [SmartUpscale](https://tanalin.com/en/projects/smart-upscale/).

Answer (score 2):

Right click on your desktop > Click on Display Settings > Set your resolution as 4K > Above it under "Scale and Layout", from the dropdown menu choose 150% (or125%) and see if it solves what you intend to do. You can also try advance scaling options over there.

Comment: I’m not sure how this is supposed to solve the problem. The OP wants 1080p (for whatever reason, performance/compatibility, doesn’t matter), not DPI scaling.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Nvidia graphics card open the video card manager->3d settings->DSR factors and set it to 4x. Then open up the monitor properties in windows and change the resolution to an upscaled resolution

https://stormystudio.com/record-4k-hd-monitor/